# Number of ways to pick $k$ integers from a multiset/bag to sum to at least $n$

Tags: combinatorics

For example, say I have the following group of numbers:

`1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3`

And I want to pick 3 of those numbers to get at least 6.

So I could pick like `3, 3, 2`, or `3, 2, 1`, or `3, 2, 1` again (each number is unique).

Is this kind of problem solvable with combinatorics? Or is it necessary to do some amount of manual enumeration? Right now the only solution I can think of is basically enumerating all the possible sums that give at least $n$, and then the only combinatorics is a bit of choosing to find out the different ways I can choose the same number from the duplicate "unique" numbers.

Comment: Well, the number of ways you can choose 3 numbers from the group of six is $\binom 6 3$ giving you the size of the sample space. That's using combinatorics in some sense. Then you need to figure out how many of those give a sum of at least 6.

Comment: The step I'm stuck on is the second part though. For example, what if you need to pick 5 from 20? Then the "figure out how many give at least X" suddenly becomes a lot harder than just "list them out and count them yourself"

Comment: There's no single answer on how to solve problems. An example, say you tripled the number of numbers, so you had six 1's, three 2's, and nine 3's, and you still picked 3 of them and wanted to know the probability the sum is at least six. You would have $\binom {18} 3$ sums in your sample space. The only combinations giving less than 6 are 111, 112, 122, or 113 if i'm not mistaken. Thus the probability is $\frac {\binom 6 3+\binom 6 2\cdot\binom 3 1+\binom 6 1\cdot \binom 3 2+\binom 6 2\cdot \binom 9 1} {\binom {18} 3}$

Comment: Got it backwards, should be 1 minus the above probability.